# IOptions and it's security ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, thread-safety

On app startup I have to provide symmetric key which will be used e.g. in controllers. I've heard that singleton isn't enough safe to keeping secrets, so I'm wondering about `IOptions` from `Microsoft.Extensions.Options`. Is `IOptions` pattern safe? Or maybe there are better alternatives for this purpose?
Currently, it looks like this:

Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<EncryptingOptions>(cfg =>
{
    cfg.SymmetricKey = symmetricKey;
});
```

E.g. controller:

```
    private readonly EncryptingOptions _encryptingOptions;
    
    public SomeController(IOptions<EncryptingOptions> encryptingOptions)
    {
        _encryptingOptions = encryptingOptions.Value;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share more details on your issue, and the code snippet? It's really not clear what you are trying to do and what you are concerned about.

Comment: "I've heard that singleton isn't enough safe to keeping secrets" . what do you mean by this. are you talking about security of in-memory data?

Comment: I edited my question. @CodingMytra, a friend once told me that a singleton causes memory leaks and can block asynchronous threads. Now I have looked a bit on the internet and I don't see any confirmation of that. So would a singleton be a good choice for storing a symmetric key?

Comment: I think you are mixing multiple things. memory leak and security these two are different concerns.  which one you want to address ?

Comment: To security. Sorry, I'm new to this topic.

Comment: As you are saying you are new to this would you kindly please specify what exactly you want to address here? what made you confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security of your secrets is not related to design patterns.

You definitely can use the option pattern for your secret keys and I recommend using it, take a look at this article from Microsoft Learn:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options

you should keep your server and your software artifact safe but sometimes we need to give access to others to do something in our servers (do not do that!), so in these cases, we can encrypt our configurations, take a look at this article which is about app-secret that is useful in your case:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows

It uses Environment Variables. but you have just made accessing that information harder not completely safe because if someone has access to your server, he/she can see anything!

honestly, you should keep your files and settings in a safe place.